# Exporting SSRS Report to PDF - Avoid extra blank spaces between Body and Header

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report where I have  Header and  body.In header I need only few details to get repeated in each page  not all so in visibility I have written expression

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber = 1, FALSE, TRUE)
```

This works fines when I preview the report.
 But when I export it to PDF in 2nd page there are so much blank space between body and header
 below is the image :

1st page

[image]

2nd page

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry! Mistakenly I have added both same image url Can you please update your question with second image...

Comment: i have updated the image

Comment: Thanks! I have added image now. And the solution is copy all textbox and tablix and put inside rectangle and check it will work. let me know if works or not.

Comment: In my Report I have added Header in which I have added various text box,Next is the body which contain Table.Now as you said I have added a rectangle in the header and moved all the textbox in that but still when i export to pdf I see empty space on all page except the first

Comment: So parameters sections inside the textbox or inside the tablix? It seems we need to use tablix inside rectangle to fix your issue. does it possible or not as per your requirement?

Comment: all the extression using parameter are in  textbox which is in header i tried putting all the textbox present in header into a rectangle which i added in header and table is in body but still it show white spaces

Comment: can you please share rdl file if possible...

Comment: Thanks for the help , it is solved .I removed all the textbox from header and added it in a rectangle which i added in body of report .in the property of rectangle i ticked the option 'Add a page break after'

Comment: Okay you can leave your answer here to help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Need to remove all the Textbox From header and Add those into a rectangle which you have added in body of report. In the property of rectangle, tick the option **'Add a page break after'**